# How do I permanently enable terminal output to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-18.04

Is there any way to always save the content of whatever is happening on terminal window to a file?

I want to save each and every command that is being executed and its output to a file to keep track of changes and I want to enable it up permanently on the terminal.

> Linux Distro: Ubuntu 18.03
>
> Terminal Program: GNOME Terminal (3.28.2)

Comment: Consider sharing information about your setup - which terminal program do you use ? How do you plan to handle output from 'visual' program (e.g., vi/emacs), which may generate lot of output, etc.

Comment: Also, what is the scope of the logging. Just specific users ? only for 'root' ? It might not be piratical to capture every input and every output. Do you need to capture ssh sessions from remote servers ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Terminal is GNOME Terminal 3.28.2. It should not be for current logged in user not necessarily root

Comment: it would be nice if there is enable/disable logging functionality. e.g. `$> enable logging [On/Off]` something like that

Answer (score 3):

One way is to run [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) and do everything you want logged in its session.

Pay attention to the caveats in the notes, though; tui programs don't play well, don't use in a pipeline or shell script, etc.

```
$ script
$ run some commands
$ exit
$ cat typescript # Default log file
```

Comment: Could you please include some snippets of code examples and the notes caveats within the answer body itself. Currently, the answer mostly resembles a [code-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: this works for me but it shows lot of junk characters in log file, do you think of any reason? I checked, its already UTF-8 format file

Answer (score 0):

One basic way is to redirect all output to `tee` which writes to a file in addition to showing it on the terminal. The basic layout is `exec > >(tee ...) 2>&1`. For example, using `tee -a` to append to the file:

```
exec > >(tee -a ~/.bash_log.out) 2>&1
```

This probably has the [same caveats as `script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html#NOTES), plus some more, for example `ls` will detect that stdout is redirected and do basic printing instead of pretty printing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

I found a nice plugin for [Terminus](https://github.com/Eugeny/terminus) which is quite popular command line tools in developer community

this is [save-output plugin](https://github.com/Eugeny/terminus-save-output) for terminus has switch to enable/disable logging the output